chemical bonding
How exactly does bonding work?
For example, in CH4 orbital overlap structure, the internet shows 4 lobes with one hydrogen attached to each...

does the s orbital of the carbon we consider after hybridization look like a lobe?
usually the s orbital is spherical, which confuses me in this case.
if we talk about the p orbitals in carbon, 3 s-p bonds are formed, hydrogen(s) to carbon(p),

The p orbital usually consists of two lobes. One lobe forms a bond with hydrogen; what does the other one do?

You have it all backwards. There is totally no such thing as hybridized $s$ orbital.


[OP] if we talk about the p orbitals in carbon, 3 s-p bonds are formed, hydrogen(s) to carbon(p), p orbital usually consists of 2 lobes, one lobe forms a bond with hydrogen, what does the other one do?

During the early days of quantum chemistry, researchers were wondering the same thing, i.e. why do I get four equivalent bonds with a tetrahedral arrangement if I start with one "s" and three "p" orbitals on the carbon atom.
The two common models to explain this are called valence bond and molecular orbital theory. In one case you work with linear combinations of the s and p orbitals of carbon ("hybridization"). In the other case, you keep the s and p orbitals, and work with linear combinations of the 4 s orbitals of hydrogen (that match the symmetry of the orbitals of the central atom). Either way, the models rationalize four equidistant hydrogen atoms in a tetrahedral arrangement.

[OP] For example, in CH4 orbital overlap structure, the internet shows 4 lobes with one hydrogen attached to each ... does the hybridized s orbital look like a lobe? usually the s orbital is spherical, which confuses me in this case.

The hydrogen orbital combined with the sp3-hybridized orbital of carbon looks "like a lobe". As you already heard in the comments, the hybridization is not happening on the hydrogen atom (it only has a single orbital in play, the 1s).

by hybridized s orbital i was trying to say the s orbital after we consider hybridisation.
but I do understand how I did sound a bit wrong.
and s oribtal of not hydrogen but of carbon..
